# Passing pointers to function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have written a program in which a function takes two pointers as arguements and that function changes the address of pointer ,so when i call the value of pointers in the main function it is displaying the same old value.

Code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sample(int *d, int *m);

int main(){
    int day=12,month=3;
    int *d,*m;
    d = &day;
    m = &month;
    printf("Day = %d \t MOnth = %d\n",*d,*m);
    sample(d,m);
    printf("Day = %d \t Month = %d\n",*d,*m);
}

void sample(int *d, int *m){
    int month = 1;
    int day = 30;
    m = &month;
    d = &day;
}
```

Based on answers to the same question on stackoverflow i even called the functions using `sample(&d,&m)` but that too did'nt work.

I even tried defining the function like :-

```
 void sample(int *d,int *m){
    int month = 1;
    int day = 30;
    *m = month;
    *d = day;
 }
```

But the program crashed.

Comment: Your second version should work... If it crashed, I'd reckon something else happened.

Comment: You are setting the local copies of the pointer arguments to the function to point at local variables in the function.  This doesn't change anything in `main()`.  You could write (in the sample function) `*d = 30; *m = 1;` (or `*d = day; *m = month;`).

Answer (score 1):

When you want to pass any variable to a function, change it in this function and return its ***new*** value, you need to pass a reference to it ([passing-by-reference](/questions/tagged/passing-by-reference)), not the variable itself ([passing-by-value](/questions/tagged/passing-by-value)).

Specifically in your case, if you want to change the addresses of `d` and `m` you need to pass *references to the addresses* you want to change. This means that your function should be modified like this :

```
void sample(int *d,int *m){
    *m = 1;
    *d = 30;
}
```

and accordingly modify the body of your `main` function like this :

```
int day=12, month=3;
sample(&day, &month);
```

---

However, if you insist in your way, the following modifications should be made :

```
void sample(int **d, int **m){
   int month = 1;
   int day = 30;
   *m = &month;
   *d = &day;
}
```

and accordingly you should change the call of the function like this :

```
int day=12, month=3;
int *d, *m;
d = &day;
m = &month;
sample(d,m);
```

Comment: Passing a pointer to pointer still passes a value; pointer to pointer is a value as much as a pointer to non-pointer is. I'd say the distinctions you're trying to  make are confusing at best and plain wrong at worst. Specifically - is passing `int*` to a function passing a reference to `int` or a value of `int*`?

Answer (score 0):

In `sample()` API you are assigning some new values to your pointers and these values are valid only within the sample API, the purpose you are passing a pointer is to retain the location where the value needs to be changed.So you shouldn't change the locaion where your pointer is pointing you just have to change the value in the location as shown below.

```
void sample(int *d,int *m)
{
   int month=1,day = 30;       
   *m = month;
   *d = day;
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand this answer

Comment: @SahibNavlani I might have mistaken your question. Are you trying to change month to day and day to month?

Comment: No ,i am trying to change the value of variable defined in main function using pointers and an external function that takes no arguement.

Comment: where you write "API" you mean "function"

Comment: @SahibNavlani and this should be in your original question, plainly and openly, in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what your function is doing:

```
void sample(int *d,int *m){  // take a temporary pointer arg
    int month = 1;           // create a temporary variable
    m = &month;              // assign the address of the temporary
                             // to the temporary pointer        
}
```

> a function takes two pointers as arguements and that function changes the address of pointer

If you really wanted that, then:

- you'd need to take pointers to pointers
- you'd need non-temporary variables to create meaningful addresses.

---

Your added example:

```
 void sample(int *d,int *m) {
    int month = 1;
    int day = 30;
    *m = month;
    *d = day;
}
```

Is ok; as in, it does something completely different from the first one, but at least has a chance of working. The only way it could crash is if the values passed to it were bad; so the problem is in the caller.

Comment: I cannot understand, can you please explain it in more detail.

Comment: @SahibNavlani Actually, no. If you're still failing at understanding now, go back, open your book, read the chapter about pointers again and *then* come back for explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the calling of the function solved the problem

```
sample(&day,&month);
```

New Code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sample(int *d,int *m);

int main(){
int day=12,month=3;
int *d,*m;
d = &day;
m = &month;
printf("Day = %d \t MOnth = %d\n",*d,*m);
sample(&day,&month);
printf("Day = %d \t Month = %d\n",*d,*m);
}

void sample(int *d,int *m){
int month = 1;
int day = 30;
*m = month;
*d = day;
}
```

Comment: `sample(&day,&month);` and `sample(d,m);` are the same